# Font loaded using StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations is not applying in Flex4.11

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts, flex4

Fonts are embedded using @font-face in CSS and generated as .swf file. In application, generated swf file is loaded using StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations() method. Embedded fonts are not applying to the controls for first time but it applies when reloading/refreshing the application.

For Ex:

CSS File:

```
@font-face {
    src: url("font\GOTHICB.ttf");
    embedAsCFF : true;
    fontFamily: GOTHIC;
    fontLookup:"embeddedCFF";
    fontWeight: normal;
}
```

In Actionscript File:

```
StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("styles.swf", true, false);
```

Please let me know if anything i missed out. Kindly share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the flashvar resourceModuleURLs to the load the font swf: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f3c.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6119c-8000

Or you could write your own custom preloader and do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response Clintm

Answer (score 0):

Using StyleManager is deprecated in newer versions of flex. Use styleManager (Lower case s) instead to get the StyleManager instance for the application.